# France/USA collaboration funding for young researcher?

Tags: funding, postdocs, united-states, europe, international

I am a French citizen, I defended my PhD in Paris in November 2014, and I am working as a post-doctoral researcher in the US since December 2014. I am working in between Astrophysics and Computer Science. I have already submitted several NSF proposals to get additional funding in the US (but I am waiting for the answers).

I am currently searching for European of French funding opportunities (1 year, 2 years, or 3 years programs) that would allow me to create my own collaboration plan between France and US. Ideally I would like to be able to travel back and forth both countries. I already have 1 lab in each country that would be interested, and if necessary I can also add one non-academic partner that is interested in my work.

To what programs should I look?

EDIT: The biggest list of potential programs, the better

Answer (score 2):

A good option seems to be a Marie Curie Global Fellowship, funded by the European Commission. See http://ec.europa.eu/research/mariecurieactions/about-msca/actions/if/index_en.htm for more information.

Note that this allows setting up a collaboration plan between any European with any non-European country, so it's more general than what you're looking for.